# Is it possible to point to alternative php.in config file using web.config file in windows server?

Tags: php, config, windows-server

I am deploying a small web platform built with PHP. He already has a hosting service and they are using Microsoft server. While deploying a couple of errors appeared. I looked around and found they were trouble with the php.ini file.

Nevertheless, I just have an ftp access to the folder where his webpage is hosted. I created another php.ini file with the configuration that I need and put in the root to his folder.

I called his hosting service, but something tells me they are going to take forever either to update their php.ini file, or make that folder use the php.ini file I left in the root.

I found that it is possible to php to have an alternative php.ini, but my question is can I specify php to take my alternative config file using the web.config file?

I have no access to it, so I thought there might be a way. If it is not possible, then I'll just call them again and again.

Thanks guys.

Comment: NOFI but hosting production PHP sites on Windows is just plain wrong. Windows and ASP.NET are as monogamously married to eachother as the letters in LAMP. There are to this day known threading bugs related to deploying PHP in IIS. I would recommend just switching to a LAMP hoster.

Comment: I recommended the same to my boss, because I read a bit about that. But this client we are dealing with gets it for free because his friends owns the hosting service company

Comment: Good friends actually provide decent support for their friends, even on freebies  ;)

Answer (score 1):

[According to Microsoft](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/enable-per-site-php-configuration-on-iis-60-and-iis-7-and-above), it is possible by setting the `PHPRC` environment variable:

```
<fastCgi>
    <application fullPath="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe" arguments="-d open_basedir=C:\Websites\Website1">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="PHPRC" value="C:\WebSites\website1" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </application>
    <application fullPath="C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe" arguments="-d open_basedir=C:\WebSites\Website2">
        <environmentVariables>
            <environmentVariable name="PHPRC" value="C:\WebSites\website2" />
        </environmentVariables>
    </application>
</fastCgi>
```